# Good answer gets removed, since it's too close to another answer in another question

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Is it okay that a good answer gets removed, since it is too similar to another answer in a linked question? I have a specific situation, but won't post links to keep this question universal.

*Context*: I was looking for a solution for a problem on Stack Overflow and found 2 questions about this, but none of the answers convince me. After some research, I found a new solution to solve my problem. I post this solution to both questions, since it answers both of them. Apparently this was wrong, since the answers were exact duplicates. One answer got deleted after some time. I saw that and also a rather unfriendly comment with it. It felt toxic: I did something productive and someone just deleted it, without even checking whether the answer was correct.

After I overcame this frustration, I tried productively changing the answer to phrase it more specific to the question. The more specific answer got deleted as well, saying that it was the exact same answer. First, that is not true, since I had made it more specific. And second, this will leave you with a situation, where new solutions to the same questions are not acceptable by mods. Now I put already more energy in this, than I cared. But other people looking for this solution will suffer, because they cannot find the modern solution.

Link to the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72411197/6276704

Link to the deleted answer, that I had adjusted:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72412046/6276704

Link to the rightfully deleted answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72411237/6276704

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the links in this version though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72411237/6296561 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72412046/6296561 (at least)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Sorry, you are referring to the wrong question in one of the links.

Comment: Nope, I just linked the first dupe and the repost of the deleted dupe, both of which matter for context.

Comment: True. But it missed the link, I was referring to. I edited the question for completeness.

Comment: If you sufficiently edited an answer to no longer be identical, you need to flag it for moderator attention, and explain why the revision is sufficient; I would personally say it isn't.

Comment: @Larnu What is missing for the answer to be sufficient in your opinion? I think the main problem is that one question's author did not know how to phrase his question.

Comment: Because the cotent is identical, with some extra text; that isn't a personalised answer to the question. If it were, none or very little would be the same.

Comment: But it does answer the question in a new way. To me the questions are duplicates, but others might disagree. If they were actually marked as duplicates, I would understand that. But they are not, so it makes no sense to me, that we don't want another different correct answer for that question.

Comment: Then Flag/VTC as a duplicate and post the answer **once**.

Comment: Question are duplicates if the **answer** is applicable to both questions.  The phrasing of the question isn’t relevant if the community moderation is being performed properly. Your comment below suggested the questions were phrased differently, but you believed your answer was applicable to both, which makes them duplicates.  **Answering both questions with the same answer isn’t appropriate.**

Comment: Somebody marked it as rude, which was definitely not my intention! So I deleted all the answers now.

Answer (score 19):

If you think the same answer works for two or more questions then that potentially makes the questions duplicates. You should then answer one of them and flag the other as a duplicate of the one you answered.

Once question A is closed as a duplicate of question B the close notice will direct people to question B whenever they happen come across question A.

We'd like to keep information concentrated where we can so that when you have a problem you don't need to read through lots of very similar questions to find scattered answers.

If you then realise the questions are not the same and they need different answers you should have flagged the deleted answer for moderator attention after you've edited it to reflect those differences so that it can be undeleted.

Comment: I have also flagged the questions as duplicates, but they are phrased very differently. While reading them, it looks different. But if you spend time with it, you realize they were asking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @Tigerware then you only need to answer one of them don't you?

Comment: I guess. But they are phrased so differently, that most people would not notice that they are duplicates.

Comment: That's a good thing. No matter how you search you find the one set of answers.

Comment: Yes, but you won't find the modern solution on one of the questions now.

Comment: I consider the questions duplicates. I don't know how you guys think about it. If they are not duplicates, the same answer still answers both questions, but then you only want it for one problem. That part makes no sense to me.

Comment: The duplication process links the questions so you're directed to the one set of answers whichever one you land on. Surely you don't want everyone to write dozens of identical answers to almost identical questions. That would be a waste of time, no?

Comment: Sometimes that would be helpful. Like here, where the questions are phrased very differently. So - It depends.

Comment: As I said, I also tried targeting the answer to each question. IMO, this would be the best case. Where you find specific answers to almost identical questions. Apparently I was wrong.